# Is there any guidance for caching patterns in ASP.NET 5

Tags: caching, serialization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.NET 5 we have two interfaces for caching IDistributedCache and IMemoryCache, and then we also have LocalCache which is an implementation of IDistributedCache that uses MemoryCache internally.

IMemoryCache seems to have the kind of api I am used to, you put in an object of whatever type and you get back an object that you can cast back to the original type. When using MemoryCache I think no serialization is involved, the object is just stored directly in memory which is why the api is more simple.

IDistibutedCache seems like what we should be using to develop scalable cloud applications but it has a less appealing api in that we pass in a byte array and get back a byte array. The objects in this case must be serializable and we must serialize them ourselves in order to put them in the cache and deserialize them after retrieval such as in this code snippet:

```
public async Task<TreeNode<NavigationNode>> GetTree()
{
    if (rootNode == null)
    {
        await cache.ConnectAsync();
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(cacheKey);
        if (bytes != null)
        {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
            rootNode = BuildTreeFromJson(json);
        }
        else
        {
            rootNode = await BuildTree();
            string json = rootNode.ToJsonCompact();

            await cache.SetAsync(
                                cacheKey,
                                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json),
                                new    DistributedCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(
                                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100))
                                    );
        }
    }

    return rootNode;
}
```

In this specific example I'm using custom serialization and deserialization becuase the object in this example needs some help with serialization because it is not just a simple class.

For more general usage of cache with easily serializable objects it seems like I should implement some kind of cache helper or wrapper around IDistributedCache, to make an api that is more similar to IMemoryCache, so that I can just pass in object and get object back by key and reduce the complexity and duplication of my caching code. Internally I suppose my CacheHelper class would just use standard json serialization or is there something else I should use?

Are there any plans for a CacheHelper of this sort in the framework itself or should I implement my own?

I'm thinking that particularly in environments like Azure I should probably implement caching for most things retrieved frequently from the SqlAzure database in order to reduce costs, and IDistributeCache allows easily plugging in different caching solutions Azure cache or Redit etc by DI.

Is this the right approach or is there any guidance for a better approach or pattern?

When using LocalCache is there any performance difference vs using MemoryCache directly?

Should we always or almost always use IDistributedCache or are there specific example scenarios where using IMemoryCache would be preferred?

Comment: I personally really don't understand why we have separate caching interfaces. The team say they are different but why do I care in my application? I should be able to switch between in-memory cache to distributed cache without any worry and they should just implement the same interface.

Comment: @tugberk there are 2 different interfaces because they don't serve the same purpose: `IMemoryCache` has been specially designed to accept  non-serializable objects that `IDistributedCache` implementations couldn't handle (e.g a `CompilationResult` or a `CompilerCacheEntry`). If you want to easily switch between in-memory and distributed caching, use `IDistributedCache`: the default implementation (`LocalCache`) uses `IMemoryCache`.

Comment: Seems to me that `IMemoryCache` is just there to solve the internal needs. I personally didn't have any cases where I have something I want to cache but it's not serializable (however, it could be just me).

Comment: and working with `IDistributedCache` and using `IMemoryCache` in it is just weird :D hard to explain to someone. In fact, I don't understand it at the first place.

Comment: seems like we should use IDistributedCache implemented by LocalCache then we can change it later to real distributed cache. But with IDistributedCache we always incur serialization which may not always be cheap. If serialization is not cheap we may want to keep the object in local memory after get from distributed cache.In single server environment it seems like I would want to store the tree in local memory to reduce IO on the local file it is built from but if I'm using LocalCache I'm still deserializing the object every time I get it from the cache which may not be saving much vs build it.

Comment: @JoeAudette when using `LocalCache`, there's absolutely no serialization, as it directly delegates the operation to `MemoryCache`, that simply relies on a dictionary to store the objects as-is.

Comment: @Pinpoint how can that be when the IDistributedCache interface requires me to serialize it to byte array just to put it there. There is no serialization inside LocalCache but I must serialize to get it in there right and deserialize it back from byte array on retrieval?

Comment: @JoeAudette ah yeah sure, but this also means that you can choose a very efficient/cheap way to "serialize" your objects, using either `BinaryWriter` or `BitConverter` for instance (stricto sensu, it's not really a serializer).

Comment: The fastest solution that we have identified is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dz_7hukyejQ , it keeps everything in RAM (64Gb+) without taxing the GC, this holds easily 300M business objects resident, and executes around 1.5 M inserts/sec and 7 M lookups a second on a 3 Ghz server(i am the author). items are accessible by key, max age expiration + prioritized. used in prod. code is here: https://github.com/aumcode/nfx/blob/master/Source/NFX/ApplicationModel/Pile/ICache.cs

Comment: @Pinpoint for the example code I posted the object is not serializable with JsonConvert so I implement a custom serialization and deserialization to json string. Then I convert the string to byte array to put it in cache. Are you saying there is an easy way to convert this object to a byte array without first serializing it to string? Even for easily serializable objects is there a tutorial you can point me to to use BinaryWriter to go back and forth to byte array so I can write a wrapper that just takes object?

Comment: Here's how we use `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` in aspnet/Security to serialize an authentication ticket: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication/DataHandler/Serializer/TicketSerializer.cs. Of course, this kind of "manual serialization" has its own downsides: you need a specific serialization format for every type you want to support, your `Write/Read` calls must respect the same order and every change made to the serialization format is a "breaking change" (that's why we use a `Version` hint)... but it's blazingly fast.

Comment: If you're looking for a `JsonConvert` equivalent that simply takes an `object` and tries to serialize it, `BinaryWriter` is clearly not the way to go.

Comment: @Pinpoint I mispoke, actually my object above can be serialized with JsonConvert it just can't be deserialized because it is a Tree whose nodes have read only collection of child nodes that can only be added with methods of the object. For this object perhaps it will be a good idea to use BinaryWriter. But for general case of typical objects we don't want to write classes like that to just to get them in and out of cache so we will in fact incur some serialization to get things in and out of LocalCache since string is easy to convert to byte[] conveniently.

Comment: Sure, for primitive types like `string`, `int`, `long`, `double` or `decimal`, `BitConverter` is clearly easier to use. For complex types, it's definitely a right mix between speed and complexity. If you don't want to choose, `IMemoryCache` is probably your best option.

Comment: @Pinpoint I guess for better scalability we want to build our apps with IDistributedCache and when really using distributed cache the serialization is to be expected, but if we deploy to a single server we get some serialization cost without benefit. So maybe we need to build a cache wrapper that by configuration can use either IMemoryCache or IDistributedCache if we really want to be able to optimize for all environments. And if deserialization is expensive and we don't want to do it on each web request we need to keep it around in memory cache after getting from distributed cache

Comment: Good question. I posted your question [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/79) on GitHub. I will create a pull request this evening for this feature.

Comment: @Pinpoint Isn't the ```BinaryFormatter``` available in DotNet Core? Could we not use that instead of ```BinaryWriter``` and ```BinaryReader``` as you can only read/write basic types with those. If it's not available it may be that you have to use a JSON or XML serializer.

Comment: @MuhammadRehanSaeed I don't think `BinaryFormatter` has been ported to CoreCLR yet. Due to its dependency on remoting, I'm not even sure it will be ported, at least in the near future.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some generic extensions for IDistributedCache that where useful to me running on .net core 3.1. You can use them to serialize and store any object.

```cs
public static class DistributedCacheExtensions
{
    public static Task SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T value)
    {
        return SetAsync(cache, key, value, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions());
    }

    public static Task SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        var val = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        var result = default(T);

        if (val == null) return result;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(val))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            result = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool TryGet<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, out T value)
    {
        var val = cache.Get(key);
        value = default(T);

        if (val == null) return false;

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(val))
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            value = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I posted [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/79) issue on the ASP.NET Caching GitHub project.

There is already a set of IDistributedCache extension methods [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/e233e59f9c4bbe7511572264c3c4f092aa0b0a3b/src/Microsoft.Framework.Caching.Abstractions/DistributedCacheExtensions.cs) that we can potentially add to (It's all open source so we can fix this ourselves and submit a pull request :)).

Note that BinaryFormatter is not available in .NET Core (Not sure if it ever will be) so I wrapped it with `#if DNX451` and included the `BinaryWriter` and `BinaryReader` extension methods which both runtimes can use. Note also that if you are using the BinaryFormatter extension methods, you will need to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your entities you want to serialize.

```
public static class CacheExtensions
{
    // Omitted existing extension methods...

    public static async Task<bool> GetBooleanAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadBoolean();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<char> GetCharAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadChar();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<decimal> GetDecimalAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadDecimal();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<double> GetDoubleAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadDouble();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<short> GetShortAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadInt16();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<int> GetIntAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<long> GetLongAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadInt64();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<float> GetFloatAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadSingle();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetStringAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(memoryStream);
            return binaryReader.ReadString();
        }
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, bool value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, char value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, decimal value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, double value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, short value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, int value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, long value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, float value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

    public static Task SetAsync(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, string value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
            binaryWriter.Write(value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }

#if DNX451
    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key)
    {
        byte[] bytes = await cache.GetAsync(key);
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }

    public static Task SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T value)
    {
        return SetAsync(cache, key, value, new DistributedCacheEntryOptions());
    }

    public static Task SetAsync<T>(this IDistributedCache cache, string key, T value, DistributedCacheEntryOptions options)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, value);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return cache.SetAsync(key, bytes, options);
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, you save my day. is there any update or GitHub repo for it.